# What does band inversion mean for occupation?

Tags: condensed-matter, physical-chemistry, orbitals, topological-insulators, tight-binding

I am thinking about Topological Insulators at the moment and am not clear about how to understand the occupation of the inversed band.
I understand that due to energetic and symmetry reasons the valence band in topological insulators will have higher energies for certain $\vec{k}$ than the conduction band and vice versa. But I have learned to understand the difference between the valence and the conduction band and in different ways which would answer the question what "is" in the conduction band differently and trying to put together these approaches.

1. From the chemist perspective, the conduction band consists out of antibonding orbitals. in introductory chemistry I learned that this antibonding property is a result of the higher energy of the antibonding orbitals; in advanced courses I learned that bonding/antibonding is more a symmetry thing which may be coincidental in most cases with the higher energy of antibonding orbitals; Following this reasoning I conclude that band inversion creates a band with energy in the valence band but with different orbital symmetries which is occupied with electrons
2. From a semiconductor chemistry course I learned that the valence band is a "electron" band and the conduction band is a "hole" band. With excitation they swap places and facilitate mobility of charge. In this picture, the inverted band is occupied with holes. This may be a oversimplification done in those courses; I am aware that holes are quasi particles and think the next point will serve the understanding better:
3. In solid state physics I learned to think about conduction bands as umklapp bands from the second Brillouin zone according to Blochs theorem, which get their hole characteristic from the inversion of their $\vec{k}$ when the grid vector $\vec{G}$ is subtracted. In this picture I would imagine the band inversion as discontinuities in the bands where energy jumps in the band occur and a part of the band suddenly exhibits lower energies (due to spin-orbit-coupling). The inverted bands would then be occupied with electrons according to their energy and the Fermi-dirac statistic and the electrons in the inverted conduction band (the one connected to the valence band) would come from the second Brillouin zone and would thus travel in the opposite direction according to their combined impulse $\vec{k}+\vec{G}$ -- which would fit the symmetry argument from point 1.

So my understanding is that the inverted bands are occupied with electrons with a higher $\vec{k}+\vec{G}$ than the valence electrons and have a very low energy compared to their impulse. I understand that this comes from Spin orbit coupling and that this is also connected to the discontinuity of this band in the second Brillouin zone. Those electrons exhibit also a different syymetry and the occupation of those states weakens the bonds of the material due to the antibonding properties of the orbital symmetry.

My question is: Is this a correct way to understand band inversion? Is there something I am missing or a major flaw in my argument?

Thank you in advance for your efforts following my thoughts and for your input and clarification!